# How to print a grayscale image as a monochrome colored image?

Tags: qt

I have a grayscale PNG image 'myImage' that I want to show as a monochrome image in color 'myColor' (blue in my case).

grayscale image:

[image: grayscale image]

```
QPainter p;
QImage mask(myImage);
p.begin(&mask);
p.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceIn);
p.fillRect(QRect(0.0,0.0,image.width(),image.height()), myColor);
p.end();
p.begin(&myImage);
p.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Overlay);
p.drawImage(0, 0, mask);
p.end();
```

The result look like this:
monochrome image:

[image: monochrome image]

Which is 'almost' what I want:
the black on the right should be fully blue
the gradient should have a color starting from blue, going to white.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw semitransparent (alphaBlue) image over white image to achieve that effect.

```
QImage mask("path/to/mask.png");
mask.invertPixels();

QImage alphaBlue(mask.width(), mask.height(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
alphaBlue.fill(Qt::blue);
alphaBlue.setAlphaChannel(mask);

QImage result(mask.width(), mask.height(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
result.fill(Qt::white);
QPainter painter(&result);

painter.drawImage(0, 0, alphaBlue);

result.save("path/to/result.png");
```